# Customizing default y-axis label in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I want to prefix a $ to the default y-axis label.  My bar chart is using values in the millions so the chart is returning value-MM (80MM, 30MM).  What I would like to do is format the y-axis like $-value-MM ($80MMm $30MM).  I have tried the code below and can't get it to work?

```
yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '$' + this.value;
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Revenue',
```

Comment: Have you customized it to `MM`? I would expect it to be `M` for million?

Comment: Dude if any of the solutions helped, mark it as the answer so that people who run into the same problem can easily find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One rather elaborate way to achieve this is to re-use the code Highcharts uses in their internal `defaultLabelFormatter` for axis that are numeric, and use it in the axis formatter.

An example of this, with your added prefix ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ynCKW/57/)):

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            var numericSymbols = Highcharts.getOptions().lang.numericSymbols;
            var i = numericSymbols && numericSymbols.length;
            var numericSymbolDetector = this.axis.isLog ? this.value : this.axis.tickInterval;
            var UNDEFINED, ret, multi;

            while (i-- && ret === UNDEFINED) {
                multi = Math.pow(1000, i + 1);
                if (numericSymbolDetector >= multi && (this.value * 10) % multi === 0 && numericSymbols[i] !== null) {
                    ret = Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value / multi, -1) + numericSymbols[i];
                }
            }

            if (ret === UNDEFINED) {
                if (Math.abs(this.value) >= 10000) { 
                    ret = Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, -1);

                } else {
                    ret = Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, -1, UNDEFINED, '');
                }
            }

            return "$"+ret; // Adding the prefix
        }
    },
}
```

A experimental short form of this would be to call the `defaultLabelFormatter` with the essential parts of the context it requires. An example of this ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ynCKW/58/)):

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return "$" + this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call({
                axis: this.axis,
                value: this.value
            });
        }
    },
}
```

As the context is incomplete it wouldn't work as expected if your axis was `datetime` or `categories` or perhaps logarithmical, but should work for numeric axis. For the full picture I suggest looking at the full `defaultLabelFormatter` implementation.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the question correctly, your data already has 'MM' suffix and you want to add the prefix '$'.

Try,

```
yAxis: {
        labels: {
            format: '${value}'
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the difference between using `format` and `formatter` is that the latter allows Highcharts to automatically abbreviate values to closest order. e.g. 100 000 to 100k, 1 000 000 to 1M etc., while format will display them as is: