# How to change y-axis value on highcharts?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a highchart for displaying certain values shown below [view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDGvS.png)

when i change the the y axis format to add a Dollar sign, the values show up like this

[click here to view img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CLbY.png)

how to overcome this ??

Comment: I gave this answer a couple of days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36120280/2732991 related.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customizing default y-axis label in Highcharts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36119462/customizing-default-y-axis-label-in-highcharts)

Comment: You could use [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter) and the related topic seems to be so related, that I see no real difference in questions - duplicate?

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your config object

```
 yAxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function(){
                            if (this.value>=0){
                                 return '$'+this.value;
                            }
                            return '- $'+ (0 - this.value);
                    }
            }         
    }
```

Comment: People downvote answers, but don't leave any reasons!